# PhpSpreadsheet Populate cells using a loop

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I am using PHP library [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) and would like to populate a spreadsheet (xlsx) using data from MySQL table using a loop to iterate through the cells and rows, something similar to this:

```
.------------------------.
|ID first_name last_name |
|1  John       Smith     |
|2  John       Doe       |
`------------------------`
```

My table will have the first row as header (bold text) and the rows below will be the data from MySQL.

Here is the script I wrote for this purpose:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:C1')->getFont()->setBold( true );

$header_row_array = ['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name'];
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $header_row_array, NULL, 'A1' );

global $wpdb;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM custom_table WHERE DATE( ts ) BETWEEN SUBDATE( NOW(), 1) and NOW()';
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT );

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
    for( $i = 2; $i <= count( $rows ) + 1; $i++ ) {
        foreach( range( 'A', 'C' ) as $v ) {
            switch( $v ) {
                case 'A': {
                    $value = $row->id;
                    break;
                }
                case 'B': {
                    $value = $row->first_name;
                    break;
                }
                case 'C': {
                    $value = $row->last_name;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( $v . $i, $value );
        }
    }
    //echo '<pre>';var_dump( $row );echo '</pre>';
}

$writer = new Xlsx( $spreadsheet );
$writer->save( 'test.xlsx' );
```

I also think these loops are a crude way to solve this, if you have any idea on improvements please share!

**The result I am getting is:**
The same row data in every row, as if the outer loop doesn't really loop through the items.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem came from your loops.

```
$rows = [
 ['id'=> 1, 'first_name'=> 'John', 'last_name'=> 'Smith'],
 ['id'=> 2, 'first_name'=> 'Jane', 'last_name'=> 'Doe'],
];

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
    for( $i = 2; $i <= count( $rows ) + 1; $i++ ) {
        foreach( range( 'A', 'C' ) as $v ) {
            switch( $v ) {
                case 'A': {
                    // $value = $row->id;
                    $value = $row['id'];
                    break;
                }
                case 'B': {
                    // $value = $row->first_name;
                    $value = $row['first_name'];
                    break;
                }
                case 'C': {
                    // $value = $row->last_name;
                    $value = $row['last_name'];
                    break;
                }
            }
            print $v.$i.' : '. $value . "\n";
        }
        print '--------' . "\n";
    }
}
```

return

```
A2 : 1
B2 : John
C2 : Smith
--------
A3 : 1
B3 : John
C3 : Smith
--------
A2 : 2
B2 : Jane
C2 : Doe
--------
A3 : 2
B3 : Jane
C3 : Doe
--------
```

**Edit**

For not thinking here is the solution

```
$i = 2;
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
    foreach( range( 'A', 'C' ) as $v ) {
        switch( $v ) {
            case 'A': {
                $value = $row->id;
                break;
            }
            case 'B': {
                $value = $row->first_name;
                break;
            }
            case 'C': {
                $value = $row->last_name;
                break;
            }
        }
        print $v.$i.' : '. $value . "\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

output

```
A2 : 1
B2 : John
C2 : Smith
A3 : 2
B3 : Jane
C3 : Doe
```

Comment: 1. I know there is a problem with the loops since the data is inserted incorrectly.
2. I used and object, not an array for `$row`.
3. I don't see how that constitutes as an answer.

Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: The array is the representation of your object. I just point that the loop the problem. You can still think 2 minutes to find what's wrong with the loop, or if you just want an answer see the edit ...

Comment: Hey Equal, of course I want to think why it's wrong! before I posted this question I was trying to think for quite a while why it doesn't work, I used a pen and paper and did my own iterations.
I still don't understand why you changes the outer for loop to foreach and took the `$i` variable outside.
I'll do some iterations and try to figure it out. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: with your original algorythm you populate sheet row 2 and 3 foreach result row (so you override the value and display only last result row).

Answer (score 7):

I know it's a little late, but I want to share my workaround for this same problem. I start where you are already fetched data from database:

```
$header_row_array = ['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name'];
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $header_row_array);
```

Since it's the first row you insert on the spreadsheet, it's not neccesary pass all the arguments to `fromArray()`, just the array containing the headers of each colum.

Next thing to do is iterate through `$rows`. With a `fromArray()` and one `foreach` statement you could get this, just adding a `counter` (not the most elegant solution, but practical).

```
$count = 2;
foreach($rows as $row){
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(array($row->id, $row->first_name, $row->last_name), null, 'A'.$count);
    $count++;
}
```

Like you did when inserted the header row, I just pass the cell of the first colum (`A`) in the current row (remember `$count` starts at `2`), the method puts the regarding data in the consecuent cells of that same row. The counter starts on 2 because `A1` is already used by the header row, so it starts at `A2` and sums up from there.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Genius with minimal code thanks!